# How to display Custom Post Type Post based on Tag with Shortcode Parameter?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields, tags

I need to search in Custom Post Type 'Case Studies' based on tags which is specified in Shortcode Parameters like

```
[casestudyhook tag="show-this-casestudy-onhome"]
```

so image | title | link of whichever case study has tag with "show-this-casestudy-onhome" will be displayed at shortcode

this is my current code in shortcode

```
<?php
function display_casestudy($atts) {

    $handlearray   =   shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'tag' => ''
        ),
    $atts );

    $cstag = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), esc_html( $handlearray['tag']), true );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'case_studies',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'tag'    => $cstag
            ),
        ),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );



    // The Loop
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  
      $return_string .= '<li><a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
    endwhile;

    return '<ul>'. $return_string .'</ul>';
    
    

    wp_reset_query();
}    

function register_csshortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('casestudyhook', 'display_casestudy');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_csshortcodes');

?>
```

Comment: What is all of the commented out code?  Also, you don't initialize `$return_string`

Comment: now? can you clarify more?

Comment: What is the taxonomy_type? What field are you matching?  This is the big problem... the tax_query is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer that depending on how you ultimately configure things - should get you where you want to go.

In your question, you had `posts_per_page` as 1.  If you only want 1 result, then that's fine. If not... modify as shown.

You also didn't initialize the concatenated string `$return_string` and finally you put the reset after the return, so it had no effect.

```
function display_casestudy( $atts ) {

    $handlearray = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'tag' => '',
        ),
        $atts
    );

    $cstag = sanitize_text_field( $handlearray['tag'] );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'case_studies',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // Putting -1 allows all results.
        'tax_query'      => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', // Use Your Taxonomy Type Here.
                'terms'    => $cstag,
                'field'    => 'slug', // This depends on how your're passing it in the $cstag.
            ),
        ),
    );

    $query         = new WP_Query( $args );
    $return_string = '';
    // The Loop.
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        $return_string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata(); // Put before Return otherwise it does nothing.
    
    return '<ul>' . $return_string . '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.! You just saved my job.!! Thanks a lot.